# Get hierarchical structure using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I have a self-referencing table with a primary key, `id` and a foreign key `parent_id`.

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PK  | NULL    | IDENTITY       | 
| parent_id  | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
| name       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I have got a table as following (reduce data for more clear)

Table `MySiteMap`

```
  Id   Name  parent_id
   1    A    NULL
   2    B    1
   3    C    1
   4    D    1

  20    B1   2  
  21    B2   2

  30    C1   3
  31    C2   3

  40    D1   4
  41    D2   4
```

I would like get the hierarchical structure using SQL Server query:

```
  A 
  |
   B
    |
    |  B1
    |  B2
   C
    |
    |  C1
    |  C2
   D
    |
    |  D1
    |  D2
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Common Table Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx).

```
WITH LeveledSiteMap(Id, Name, Level)
AS
(
    SELECT Id, Name, 1 AS Level
    FROM MySiteMap
    WHERE Parent_Id IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT m.Id, m.Name, l.Level + 1
    FROM MySiteMap AS m
        INNER JOIN LeveledSiteMap AS l
        ON m.Parent_Id = l.Id
)
SELECT *
FROM LeveledSiteMap
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
;WITH CTE(Id, Name, parent_id, [Level], ord) AS (
    SELECT 
        MySiteMap.Id, 
        CONVERT(nvarchar(255), MySiteMap.Name) AS Name, 
        MySiteMap.parent_id, 
        1,
        CONVERT(nvarchar(255), MySiteMap.Id) AS ord
    FROM MySiteMap
    WHERE MySiteMap.parent_id IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        MySiteMap.Id, 
        CONVERT(nvarchar(255), REPLICATE(' ', [Level]) + '|' + REPLICATE(' ', [Level]) + MySiteMap.Name) AS Name, 
        MySiteMap.parent_id, 
        CTE.[Level] + 1,
        CONVERT(nvarchar(255),CTE.ord + CONVERT(nvarchar(255), MySiteMap.Id)) AS ord
    FROM MySiteMap
        JOIN CTE ON MySiteMap.parent_id =CTE.Id
    WHERE MySiteMap.parent_id IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT Name
FROM CTE
ORDER BY ord
```

For this:

```
A
 | B
  |  B1
  |  B2
 | C
  |  C1
  |  C2
 | D
  |  D1
  |  D2
```

Answer (score 1):

I started with a query, (but when I check it now it is similar to Mark.)

*I will add it anyway*, while I created also a [**sqlfiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3a276/1) with mine and Mark query.

```
WITH tList (id,name,parent_id,nameLevel)
AS
(
    SELECT t.id, t.name, t.parent_id, 1 AS nameLevel
    FROM t as t
    WHERE t.parent_id IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT tnext.id, tnext.name, tnext.parent_id, tList.nameLevel + 1
    FROM t AS tnext
    INNER JOIN tList AS tlist
        ON tnext.parent_id = tlist.id
)
SELECT id,name,isnull(parent_id,0) 'parent_id',nameLevel FROM tList order by nameLevel;
```

A good blog:
[**SQL Query – How to get data in Hierarchical Structure?**](http://chiragvidani.blogspot.se/2011/10/sql-query-how-to-get-data-in.html)

Answer (score 0):

i know changing the structure of a table is always a critical operation but since sql server 2008 introduced the HierarchyId Datatype i really like workig with it. Maybe have a look at:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37171/HierarchyID-Data-Type-in-SQL-Server
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/740553/Hierarchy-ID-in-SQL-Server

I am sure you will understand quickly how to use this datatype and his functions. The SQL Code using this datatype is more structured and has better performance than CTE's.